# How To Get Multiple Array Value Based On Another Array In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't know what must be title for my question, I think it's so complicated. So, I have A array:

```
["87080207", "87101133", "91140156"]
```

And B Array:

```
 ["97150575", "97150575", "90141063"]
```

This B array, I put on html `select` value. Each of them(A and B array) is related. I need to show `87080207,87101133` (A array) when I choose value `97150575` (B array). 
I have tried, but it didn't work.This is my code:

```
var a=[];
var b=[];
var arrayLength = dataComponentValuation.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
   a.push(dataComponentValuation[i].valuated);
   b.push(dataComponentValuation[i].valuator);
}
var ajoin = a.join();
var bjoin = b.join();
$('#valuatedEmpCompId_before').val(ajoin);
$('#valuator_before').val(bjoin);
```

In `select`, I put a function, this is it:

```
function emptyValuated() {
    var valby = $("#valBy").val(); //chosen value from select
    var b_valby = $("#valuator_before").val();

    var b_valuated = $("#valuatedEmpCompId_before").val();
    if(b_valby != ''){
        if(valby != b_valby)
        {
            $("#valuatedEmpCompId").val('');
        }
        else{            
             $("#valuatedEmpCompId").val(b_valuated);
        }

    }
    else{      

        $("#valuator_before").val(valby);
        $("#valuatedEmpCompId").val(b_valuated);
    }
}
```

Help me please...

Comment: Use Associative array to map array key with value in javascript.

Comment: If there is no logical or mathematical correlation between the items then you should utilize a Map object with keys and a values array holding all numbers related with the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, you could use an object as reference to the values of array A.

```js
var arrayA = ["87080207", "87101133", "91140156"],
    arrayB = ["97150575", "97150575", "90141063"],
    object = Object.create(null);

arrayB.forEach(function (b, i) {
    object[b] = object[b] || [];
    object[b].push(arrayA[i]);
});

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess nowadays the Map object is a perfect solution for these jobs.

```js
var arrayA = ["87080207", "87101133", "91140156"],
    arrayB = ["97150575", "97150575", "90141063"],
     myMap = arrayB.reduce((p,c,i) => p.has(c) ? p.set(c, p.get(c).concat(arrayA[i]))
                                               : p.set(c,[arrayA[i]])
                                               , new Map());
console.log(myMap.get("97150575"));
console.log(myMap.get("90141063"));
```

Comment: while i really appreciate your answers, your formatting makes it difficult (for me) to read it.